# Minimum cut set for directed s-t cut

Tags: graph-theory

I am given a directed graph $G=(V,E)$, with vertices $s,t\in V$.

I need to find an s-t cut with the minimum number of edges crossing it from s towards t, i.e. for every cut $S\subseteq V$ such that $s\in S, t\notin S$, the number of crossing edges is defined as $N(S)=|\{(u\rightarrow v)\in E : u\in S, v\notin S\}|$. The desired cut is one for which $N(S)$ is minimal.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that I would approach this problem is by trying to use the theory behind networks and flows, in particular the *Max-Flow Min-Cut* theorem.

Consider the network $N=(V,A)$ which is constructed by letting V be the same as in $G$, and by letting $A$ be the set of directed edges from $E$ except with the additional requirement that 
\begin{equation}
c(e)=1 \hspace{2mm} \forall \hspace{1mm} e \in A
\end{equation}

Now, when we take a cut $(S, V-S)$, we will have $cap(S,V-S)$ being equal to the number of edges that have tails in $S$ and heads in $V-S$. At this point, the *Max-Flow Min-Cut* theorem guarantees that we will be able to find a cut where the value of the flow is equal to the capacity of the cut, and importantly that **this cut is a minimum cut**, meaning the number of arcs coming out of $S$ to $V-S$ is a minimum also.

In terms of actually computing this, one useful algorithm for solving the *Max-Flow Min-Cut* problem is the **Ford-Fulkerson Max Flow Labeling Algorithm** (explained in detail [here](http://www.isa.ewi.tudelft.nl/~melissen/Onderwijs/IN2805_I%20Optimalisering/Ford-Fulkerson%20Max%20Flow%20Labeling%20Algorithm.htm)) which basically iterates finding augmenting paths and augmenting the graph until a guaranteed maximum flow is found. Hope that helps!